# React/Material UI: css content property

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to set `content: ""` on my `i` element:

```
   "& i::before": {
      content: ""
    },
    "& i::after": {
      content: ""
    },
```

The style is not applied and when I look in devtools I get invalid property value:
[image]

When I do this in plain HTML/CSS, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work for me, I managed to do:

`content: "''"`

or

`content: '""'`

So, looks like using only one `''` or `""`, the code/browser doesn't understand you are setting an "empty" value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set it in devTools like: `content: ""`?

[Image devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lnn1.png)

Comment: I did, that worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).